# Most EFFICIENT way to merge multiple PNGs in PHP

Tags: php, performance, image, merge, png

I run a website that needs to routinely loop through a bunch of PNGs with transparency's and merge them together. Sometimes this can be a LONG process so I was wondering what is the most efficient way to do this. I'm using GD as I hear ImageMagick isn't really any FASTER..

```
$firstTime = true;  // need to know if it's the first time through the loop
$img = null;        // placeholder for each iterative image
$base = null;       // will become the final merged image
$width = 0;
$height = 0;

while( $src = getNextImageName() ){
    $imageHandle = imagecreatefrompng($src);
    imageAlphaBlending($imageHandle, true);
    imageSaveAlpha($imageHandle, true);

    if( $firstTime ){
        $w = imagesx( $img );       // first time in we need to
        $h = imagesy( $img );       // save the width & height off
        $firstTime = false;
        $base = $img;               // copy the first image to be the 'base'
    } else {
        // if it's not the first time, copy the current image on top of base
        // and then delete the current image from memory
        imagecopy($base, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h);
        imagedestroy($img);
    }
}

// final cleanup
imagepng($base);
imagedestroy($base);
```

Comment: Have you confirmed which part is slow by profiling? What are the implementations of those other functions?

Comment: you want to make it more efficient or faster? with many images, you can do the merging in parallel

Comment: I have no profiled anything in particular. I am using all GD PHP functions. GetNextImageName() is a mock function -- pretend it pops the next item off of an array... it's just a mechanism to deliver the source file names.

I should have been more clear about effeciency vs speed. I want this to be FASTER. I just timed this script while merging 9 layers (2750x2500px - big images!). It took 1:45 from my local machine. How would I code this to work in parallel?

Comment: @AlexanderLarikov - I've seen a lot of tests online that show imageMagick isn't any faster. Do you believe this to not be the case?

Comment: @captain_jim1 I'm gonna go out on a limb here, is this to be put on to a production server when it's finsihed? Have you tried it on the server? It might be much faster than your home PC ;)

Comment: Since you're working with pictures of such size, I'd recommend you to use queues. For an example: Youtube doesn't encode the video in the POST request, but puts it in a queue that is continuously processed by a server farm. In this instance, you can use a native application (written in C++) to process the queue. The process will be asynchronous, but there will be no performance problems.

Comment: @DannyBeckett - actually no, this will always be run from my local machine. I only host small sites on godaddy so I don't think they'd be much faster :-x.

Comment: @Zanathel - I'm not sure how a queue will help me with my problem. I essentially want to click a button and have the merged file pop out. A queue doesn't make this happen any faster.

Comment: Well, I thought you were going to use this on a public website, where multiple compositions and the memory involved in the process would not have been feasible. If you're just running it locally, you  might as well use `system` as a means to execute local processes that will do the job for you, like aebersold suggests.

Comment: @captain_jim1 "I essentially want to click a button and have the merged file pop out" Sure, add more RAM and CPUs.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely give ImageMagick a try. It's easy to implement, just use `exec('composite 1.png 2.png');`. It's well documented, not bound to PHPs memory limits and the performance is ok.

In addition, ImageMagick works great as a stand-alone for bash scripting or another terminal functions which means what you learn is useful outside of PHP.

Answer (score 1):

According to [a benchmark](http://sven.webiny.com/php-gd-vs-imagemagick-benchmark/), ImageMagick is faster than GD. This would be a start at least.

I don't know whether you could also increase the priority of PHP to Above Normal/High?